# How to cache the SSL Handshake and other Network elements in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, ssl

I am developing a flutter application with network activities. To get data, I am connecting to a `REST API` which is pretty fast. You can see the `postman` performance of an `API` call below.

[image]

Then, when I execute the same `API` in flutter, this is what I got.

[image]

If you see, the secret is that `postman` cached the DNS Lookup, TCP Handshake and SSL Handshake. But in flutter the "Connection established" time is high, which I believe it does not do any caching.

Below is my code, connecting to network.

**LoadingScreen2Controller**

```
class LoadingScreen2Controller {

  Future<void> initProcess(BuildContext context) async {
    final FirebaseAuthService firebaseAuthService =
        Provider.of<FirebaseAuthService>(context, listen: false);
    final RoleService roleService =
        Provider.of<RoleService>(context, listen: false);

 
    fireauth.User? user = firebaseAuthService.getUser();

    if (user == null) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
          '/login-select', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
    } else {
     
      String authToken = await firebaseAuthService.getUser()!.getIdToken();
      await roleService.getAllRoles(authToken); // PAY ATTENTION HERE!

      Navigator.of(context)
          .pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/home', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
    }
  }
}
```

**RoleService**

```
class RoleService with ChangeNotifier {
  NavLinks _navLinks = NavLinks();
  late List<Role> _roles;

  /// Return roles
  List<Role> returnRoles() {
    return _roles;
  }

  /// Get all Roles
  Future<void> getAllRoles(String authToken) async {
    try {
      var data = await http.get(
        Uri.parse(_navLinks.getAllRoles()),
        headers: {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Bearer $authToken"},
      );
      var jsonData =
          convert.json.decode(data.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
      _roles = jsonData.map<Role>((json) => new Role.fromJson(json)).toList();
      print(_roles);
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
      throw error;
    }
  }
}
```

All of my API calls are from the same URI. This "no caching" behavior is a problem for me because if I make more network calls in a row, it will take more time. For an example, if I make like 5 network calls it will take 7 seconds so on.

How can I cache the **DNS Lookup, TCP Handshake and SSL Handshake** in flutter?

Comment: I don't think that there is a library or like so for that, you should do it manually. See if this helps: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/InternetAddress-class.html

Comment: I've never heard of "caching" the TCP handshake, I don't even know what that might mean. TCP connections do stay open until they are closed. They might be closed on purpose by the app or they might close because of a timeout. SSL does have some "resumption" modes that do faster subsequent handshakes based on information cached from an earlier full exchange. Typically those details are configured at a fairly low level in the SSL library to values that represent a sensible balance of security and performance.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Okay. My naming could be wrong then. But if you see the Postman image I put on, you can clearly see something is saving time right?

Comment: I see the image, I'm not complaining about your naming it's the image that I find confusing. Perhaps one of the TCP/IP experts will come around and understand that. If not you can ask a specific question just about TCP "caching" as that image claims to be demonstrating. Now when you say "...if I make 5 network calls..." are you describing 5 calls in one process or are you running the process 5 times? 1.5 seconds to establish a connection is quite high. If you capture packets with Wireshark you should be able to see exactly where the bottlenecks are.